# Visual Basic, SQL cannot be closed

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, sqlconnection, sqlclient, sqlconnection.close

I'm doing VB project for my exam but when I start my code it says

> Hata occurred. Error: Connection could not be closed, connection state is open.

Here is my code:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Private SqlBaglanti As New SqlConnection(SqlBaglantiCumlesi())
    Private OgrenciBilgileriSqlDA As SqlDataAdapter

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            SqlBaglanti.Open()
            OgrenciBilgileriniGetir()
            Dim Sorgu As String = "SELECT * FROM OgrenciTablo"

            ' SqlDataAdapter oluşturun
            OgrenciBilgileriSqlDA = New SqlDataAdapter(Sorgu, SqlBaglanti)

            ' SqlCommandBuilder kullanarak Insert, Update ve Delete komutlarını otomatik oluşturun
            Dim SqlKomutOlusturucu As New SqlCommandBuilder(OgrenciBilgileriSqlDA)
            OgrenciBilgileriSqlDA.InsertCommand = SqlKomutOlusturucu.GetInsertCommand
            OgrenciBilgileriSqlDA.UpdateCommand = SqlKomutOlusturucu.GetUpdateCommand
            OgrenciBilgileriSqlDA.DeleteCommand = SqlKomutOlusturucu.GetDeleteCommand

            ' DataSet'i doldurun
            OgrenciBilgileriSqlDA.Fill(CengizhanOkulVTDS, "OgrenciTablo")
            OgrenciTabloBS.DataSource = CengizhanOkulVTDS.Tables("OgrenciTablo")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Hata Oluştu.Lütfen Sistem Yöneticiniz ile bağlantı kurunuz. Hata: " & ex.Message, "Hata")
        Finally
            SqlBaglanti.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnKaydet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnKaydet.Click
        VTyeKaydet()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSil_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSil.Click
        Dim Satir As DataRowView = OgrenciTabloBS.Current
        Dim Mesaj As String = String.Format("{0} {1} isimli Öğrenciyi silmek istediğinize emin misiniz?", Satir("Adi"), Satir("Soyadi"))
        If MessageBox.Show(Mesaj, "Uyarı", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) = DialogResult.Yes Then
            OgrenciTabloBS.RemoveCurrent()
            VTyeKaydet()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub VTyeKaydet()
        Try
            Me.Validate()
            OgrenciTabloBS.EndEdit()
            If OgrenciBilgileriSqlDA.Update(CengizhanOkulVTDS, "OgrenciTablo") > 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Yapılan tüm değişiklikler başarı ile kaydedildi.", "Bilgi")
                ' ButonlariKullan() fonksiyonunu eklemiş olmanız gerekiyor
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Hata oluştu. Hata: " & ex.Message, "Hata")

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub OgrenciBilgileriniGetir()
        Dim Sorgu As String = "SELECT * FROM OgrenciTablo"
        Dim SqlKomut As New SqlCommand(Sorgu, SqlBaglanti)

        Try
            SqlBaglanti.Open()

            If Not CengizhanOkulVTDS.Tables.Contains("OgrenciTablo") Then
                CengizhanOkulVTDS.Tables.Add("OgrenciTablo")
            Else
                CengizhanOkulVTDS.Tables("OgrenciTablo").Clear()
            End If

            OgrenciBilgileriSqlDA.Fill(CengizhanOkulVTDS, "OgrenciTablo")
            OgrenciTabloBS.DataSource = CengizhanOkulVTDS.Tables("OgrenciTablo")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Hata oluştu. Hata: " & ex.Message, "Hata")
        Finally
            SqlBaglanti.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am trying to start my VB code, and I am trying to add data with form application to SQL Server

Comment: You should not be opening the connection in the first place, so there should be no need to close it. When you call `Fill` or `Update` on a data adapter, it will open the connection if necessary and then leave it in the same state it found, so it will close it if it opened it in the first place. When using a data adapter, you only have to explicitly open the connection if you want to use multiple adapters without closing the connection in between.

Comment: In your `OgrenciBilgileriniGetir` method, what is the point of the `SqlKomut` variable? You never use it. You use a data adapter that already has its commands populated.

Comment: You should strive to write code according to the DRY principle: Don't Repeat Yourself. Write code to perform a task once and once only. If the task needs to be performed in various places, put the code in a method and call that method in those places. You have repeated code in your `Form1_Load` and `OgrenciBilgileriniGetir` methods. You should put the code to initialise the data adapter in one method and the code to retrieve data in another. Call both methods from the `Load` event handler and then call only the second method when you need to refresh the data.

Comment: I suggest that you fix the issues I mentioned above and see whether the error persists. If it does, debug your code to find out exactly where the exception is thrown. Don't just rely on your own message dialogues. Set a breakpoint and step through the code to see exactly what happens, then relay that information to us. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn now, as it's something every developer needs to know.

Comment: Also do not cache connection or adapter objects. Create them when you need them, dispose with `Using`.

Comment: @Charlieface, further to that, given that you generally want to use a data adapter to both retrieve and save, I'd suggest writing a method that creates the data adapter and returns it. That way, you can call that method when you want to retrieve data and when you want to save data without having to write the code twice. The creation of the connection would be done in that same method.

Comment: BTW, calling `GetInsertCommand`, etc, on the command builder and setting the properties of the data adapter is pointless. All you need to do is create the command builder and that's it. Everything else is done automatically. The only reason to do what you're doing is if you want to modify the commands rather than use the defaults.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using tags. The VS Code tag description says specifically that it is for questions about VS Code, not about code written in VS Code. Also, the question has nothing to do with SQL. It's about the `SqlClient` ADO.NET provider and specifically the `SqlConnection` class. Please be more precise with your tag usage. People follow specific tags for a reason and you will be wasting their time if you bring irrelevant questions to their attention.